# How to make QR Barcode using c#

Tags: c#, barcode

I want to make a barcode with c# and put it in a picture file.
please help me.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Share what you have so far.

Comment: How about http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20574/Open-Source-QRCode-Library or http://code-bude.net/2013/10/17/qrcoder-eine-open-source-qr-code-implementierung-in-csharp/

Comment: Really? I can find lots. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=qr+codes+in+c%23&oq=qr+codes+in+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2778j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=qr+code+c%23

Comment: I googled the title of your question. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+make+QR+Barcode+using+c%23&oq=How+to+make+QR+Barcode+using+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.689j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 The first result is a stackoverflow post, with an answer containing a link to an open source library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Programm
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.QRCode qrcode = new System.QRCode();
    }
}
```

***Note:*** It is just a joke corresponding to the zero-level OP effort, even for google.

Comment: What puzzles me is that it's actually less effort to search on Google than it is to ask a question here. Questions like this really deserve to be closed.